# How to remove a "ghost" file icon from the Windows Vista Home Premium desktop

Tags: windows-vista

I have a file with a .VOB extension, allegedly of the size .99GB, on my desktop, but I can't get rid of it or do anything with it. It's just stuck there. Is there a painless way to make it go away that doesn't involve digging into the scary areas of Windows where I don't want to go?

Answer (score 2):

You want to delete the file using the Command Prompt. (It's not scary at all!)

First open a command prompt window at the Desktop, following the steps [here](http://www.whoismadhur.com/2008/06/05/how-to-open-command-prompt-by-right-click-menu-in-vista/):

http://www.whoismadhur.com/2008/06/05/how-to-open-command-prompt-by-right-click-menu-in-vista/

Next you can use the command

`del <FILENAME>.VOB` to delete your file. Replace `<FILENAME>` with the name of your file.

Also:

To see the list of files on your Desktop, just type `dir` right after you open the command prompt following the first step above.

Answer (score 1):

If you can’t remove the file even from command prompt, do a `chkdsk /f` .

Comment: What good will this do?

Comment: It will remove invalid file entries from the MFT.

Answer (score 0):

Is it actually clickable or really a 'ghost'/artifact type thing?

If its the latter, click and drag the 'real' icon somewhere.